# Как определить что звонок завершился? Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Нужно определить что вызов завершился, т.е. пользователь поговорил и завершил разговор, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Зарегистрировать [broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) на `PHONE_STATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зарегестрировать Receiver в Манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver">  
       <intent-filter>  
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">       
       </action></intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Добавить разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">  
</uses-permission>
```

Реализовать слушателя:

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver";
    Context mContext;
    String incoming_number;
    private int prev_state;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phoneNr = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
        mContext = context;
    }

    /* Наш слушатель */
    public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){

           if( incomingNumber != null && incomingNumber.length() > 0 ) 
            incoming_number = incomingNumber; 

            switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
                        prev_state=state;
                        break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                                Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                                prev_state=state;
                                break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_number);

                    if((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                        prev_state=state;
                        //Завершенный вызов, на который был дан ответ
                    }
                    if((prev_state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)){
                        prev_state=state;
                        //Вызов, который был отклонен или пропушен
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```